# Classifying lexemes in a given C program

Tags: c, parsing

Please review my code and tell where I can improve my program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
#define TOKEN_SIZE 32
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

int isKeyword(const char* token)
{
    const char keywords[32][20]={"auto","break","case","char",
                                "const","continue","default","do","double",
                                "else","enum","extern","float",
                                "for","goto","if","int","long",
                                "register","return","short","signed",
                                "sizeof","static","struct","switch",
                                "typedef","union","unsigned",
                                "void","volatile","while"};
    for(int i=0;i<32;i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(token,keywords[i])==0)
            return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

int isIntLiteral(const char* token)
{
    for(int i=0;token[i]!=(char)NULL;i++)
    {
        if(!isdigit(token[i]))
            return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
} 

int isFloatLiteral(const char* token)
{
    if(isdigit(token[0]))
    {
        for(int i=1;token[i]!=(char)NULL;i++)
        {
            if(!isdigit(token[i]) && (token[i])!='.')
                return FALSE;
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
} 

int isCharLiteral(const char* token)
{
    if(token[0]=='\'' && strlen(token)==3 && token[2]=='\'') 
        return TRUE;
    else
        return FALSE;
}

int isLiteral(const char* token)
{
    if(isCharLiteral(token)||isIntLiteral(token)||isFloatLiteral(token))
        return TRUE;
    else
        return FALSE;
}

int isIdentifier(const char* token)
{
    if(isalpha(token[0]) || token[0]=='_')
    {
        for(int i=1;token[i]!=(char)NULL;i++)
        {
            if(!isalnum(token[i]))
                return FALSE;
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

int isOperator(const char* token)
{
    const char operators[41][10] = {".","->","++","--","!","~","(type)","*","&",
                                 "sizeof","*","/","%","+","-","<<",">>","<",
                                 "<=",">",">=","==","!=","&","^","|","&&","||",
                                 "?:","=","+=","-=","*=","/=","%=","&=","^=",
                                 "|=","<<=",">>=",","};

    for(int i=0;i<41;i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(token,operators[i])==0)
            return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

FILE* readFile(int param1,char* param2[])
{
    if(param1<2) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"No file specifed to read. \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(param1>2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Too many arguments for read to perform. \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen(param2[1],"r");

    if(!fp)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"File access denied on read. \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return fp;
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{

    FILE *fp = readFile(argc,argv);

    char *token;
    char string[BUFFER_SIZE];
    const char delimiters[]=" .,;!=\n";

    fgets(string,sizeof string, fp);
    while(string!=(char *)NULL || (strcmp(string,"\n"))==0)
    {
        token = strtok(string,delimiters);

        while(token!=NULL)
        {
            if(isKeyword(token))
                printf("%s is a keyword. \n",token); 
            else if(isOperator(token))
                printf("%s is an operator. \n",token);
            else if(isIdentifier(token))
                printf("%s is an identifier. \n",token);
            else if(isLiteral(token))
                printf("%s is a literal. \n",token);
            else
                printf("Unrecognized token : %s \n",token);

            token = strtok(NULL,delimiters);
        }
        fgets(string,sizeof string, fp);
    }   

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}`
```

Comment: What if i want to extract keyword from a given statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove all these literals from the stack and place them in the `.rodata`/`.const` section of the executable image:

```
const char keywords[32][20]={"auto","break","case","char",
                            "const","continue","default","do","double",
                            "else","enum","extern","float",
                            "for","goto","if","int","long",
                            "register","return","short","signed",
                            "sizeof","static","struct","switch",
                            "typedef","union","unsigned",
                            "void","volatile","while"};
```

One very good way to do that would be to make it an array of pointers:

```
const char *keywords[]=
{
    "auto","break","case","char",
    "const","continue","default","do","double",
    "else","enum","extern","float",
    "for","goto","if","int","long",
    "register","return","short","signed",
    "sizeof","static","struct","switch",
    "typedef","union","unsigned",
    "void","volatile","while"
};
```

Similar considerations should be applied to the literal array in the `isOperator()` function.

Regarding this line:

```
for(int i=0;i<32;i++)
```

Do not use 'magic' numbers (other than `0` and `1`) in the code as they are a maintenance nightmare. I suggest:

```
for(size_t i=0; i<(sizeof(keywords)/sizeof(char*)); i++)
```

Regarding this line:

```
for(int i=0;token[i]!=(char)NULL;i++)
```

This will not work quite correctly, as `NULL` is the size of a pointer and I think the code is looking for `'\0'`, not `NULL`.

I suggest:

Note, no need to make any comparison as the contents of `token[i]` is either in the range `0x01`...`0xFF` or `0x00` - and `0x00` will be seen as false.

```
for(int i=0; token[i];i++)
```

When `#define`ing a numeric value, always wrap the value in parens to avoid any possibility of 'text replacement' errors.

Regarding these lines:

```
fgets(string,sizeof string, fp);
while(string!=(char *)NULL || (strcmp(string,"\n"))==0)
```

1. `string` will NEVER be `NULL` because `string` is not a pointer
2. there is never a need to cast `NULL`

I suggest:

```
while( fgets(string,sizeof string, fp) )
```

To get the actual reason that a call to `fopen()` fails, change this:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(param2[1],"r");

if(!fp)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"File access denied on read. \n");
    exit(1);
}
```

to: (`perror()` will output the system message for the current value of 'errno')

```
FILE *fp = NULL;
if( NULL ==( fp = fopen(param2[1],"r") ) )
{ // then fopen failed:
    perror( "fopen for input file failed" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

I suggest that `main()` check the number of parameters and if not correct, then output a 'USAGE' statement and exit.  This would greatly simplify the `readfile()` function, which is not actually reading a file, but rather just opening a file.

There are plenty of other details that could be improved, but the above should get you started.

Comment: I'd write your "array size" expression as `sizeof keywords / sizeof *keywords` so it's automatically right regardless of the type of `keywords[]`.  And you're right about casting `NULL` to `char`, but not because of the _size_ of the value (the problem is that C allows `NULL` to be `(char*)0`, which isn't necessarily represented by zero, and casting to arithmetic types doesn't have to spot `NULL` and convert it to `0`).

Answer (score 3):

### stdbool.h

I suggest using `#include <stdbool.h>` and the `bool` type instead of defining `TRUE` and `FALSE` yourself.

### Literals not recognized by your program

1. Float literals: `1.0e+19`, `1.0f`
2. Int literals: `-1`, `100L`, `0xdead`
3. Char literals: `'\n'`, `'\007'`

### Operators

Currently there are two operators that won't actually be checked correctly:

1. `(type)` for casts.
2. `?:` for the ternary operator.

Plus, since you use `strtok` on your input with these delimiters: `" .,;!=\n"`, you also won't see any `. , ! =` operators since they will be stripped out by `strtok`.

### Tokenizing

If you have some input such as `foo+bar`, your program will consider the whole expression as one token.  It will then fail to pass the "identifier" test because of the `+` character.  Using `strtok` to tokenize your input isn't sufficient for the C language.  However, if you are assuming that your input has spaces around everything, then it will work.